# What are the "host and target platforms" of a dependency?

Tags: dependencies, nix, nixos, package-management

https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-stdenv-dependencies-reference says:

> Dependencies can be broken down along three axes: **their host and
> target platforms relative to the new derivation’s**, and whether they
> are propagated. The platform distinctions are motivated by cross
> compilation; see Cross-compilation for exactly what each platform
> means. [1] But even if one is not cross compiling, the platforms imply
> whether or not the dependency is needed at run-time or build-time, a
> concept that makes perfect sense outside of cross compilation. By
> default, the run-time/build-time distinction is just a hint for mental
> clarity, but with strictDeps set it is mostly enforced even in the
> native case.
>
> The extension of PATH with dependencies, alluded to above, proceeds
> according to the relative platforms alone. The process is carried out
> only for dependencies whose host platform matches the new derivation’s
> build platform i.e. dependencies which run on the platform where the
> new derivation will be built. [2] For each dependency  of those
> dependencies, dep/bin, if present, is added to the PATH environment
> variable.
>
> A dependency is said to be propagated when some of its
> other-transitive (non-immediate) downstream dependencies also need it
> as an immediate dependency. [3]
>
> It is important to note that **dependencies are not necessarily
> propagated as the same sort of dependency that they were before**, **but
> rather as the corresponding sort so that the platform rules still line
> up**. **To determine the exact rules for dependency propagation, we start
> by assigning to each dependency a couple of ternary numbers (-1 for
> build, 0 for host, and 1 for target) representing its dependency type,
> which captures how its host and target platforms are each “offset”
> from the depending derivation’s host and target platforms.** The
> following table summarize the different combinations that can be
> obtained: ...

What are the three axes? I only saw two:

- their host and target platforms relative to the new derivation’s,
- whether they are propagated.

What do the following parts from the quote mean:

- the "host and target platforms" of a dependency, as in the first paragraph;
- "build", as in "assigning to each dependency a couple of ternary numbers (-1 for build, 0 for host, and 1 for target) representing its dependency type" in the last paragraph; (Is "build" another platform of a dependency, besides the dependency's "host and target platforms"?)
- "their host and target platforms relative to the new derivation’s";
- the two sentences in bold and in the last paragraph.

?

Can someone rephrase it in a way easier to understand?

Answer (score 2):

So there are many questions here (and I saw you also asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77515761/how-should-this-table-of-platforms-of-dependencies-be-read/77526392#77526392), where I just provided a shorter explanation).

So first, **long story short**: if you only want to compile a normal software (i.e. not a compiler), you certainly want to use:

- `nativeBuildInputs` for softwares that most be available during the compilation (e.g. `pkg-config`, `cmake`, `unzip`),
- and all the rest should go to `buildInputs` (e.g. all the libraries your program use like `openssl`, `ffmpeg`…).

If you have a doubt on where a package should go, you can run `rg yourPackage` (`rg` is a faster and fancier `grep -r`) in the nixpkgs repository and see what other did.

Now, regarding your questions: so to answer the first question, I think that they just mean that they see the tuple `(host, target, propagated)` ∈ ({-1,0,1} x {-1,0,1} x {0,1}) as three axes, hence you have 3x3x2 options for each dependency.

Then, the first thing to know is that you often use different machines when dealing with programs, that might run on different architectures, notably when cross-compiling (e.g. you compile on x86_64 a program for Arm v8, maybe because your Intel laptop runs faster than your Raspberry Pi, or because you don't have a Raspberry Pi with you):

- `build` is the machine that will **compile** your software (think "your laptop", or the servers of hydra if your program is integrated in nixpkgs).
- `host` is the machine where the program will **run** on (think "a Raspberry Pi", or the computer of the people that will use the program, maybe its an Apple silicon M2…)
- `target` is a bit more special, and only applies when the software you compile is a compiler (e.g `g++`). Indeed, weirdly enough, when you compile a compiler, you need to specify the architecture on which the programs compiled with your compiler will be run.

So for instance, if I compile `g++` on my laptop, in such a way that `g++` will be run on a MacOS laptop, and will be used to compile binaries that will be run on a Raspberry Pi, then:

- `build` will be your laptop (say it is `x86_64-linux`)
- `host` will be the Mac (say it is `aarch64-darwin`)
- `target` will be the Raspberry Pi (say it is `aarch64-linux`)

This should answer your questions 2 & 3.

To answer question 4, I will re-use the example given [here](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#possible-dependency-types) that you can read for further details and examples. So first, a dependency is any program/library that is needed somehow to compile/run the program, or, possibly, to run the program that will be later compiled when you are compiling a compiler. For instance, to compile `g++`, you will need `gcc`. So `gcc` is a dependency of `g++`. But you need to know which "flavor" of `gcc` you need to compile `g++`: since you will run `gcc` on your laptop, and use the compiled `g++` on the mac, you expect the `gcc` flavor that runs on `x86_64-linux` and compiles to `aarch-darwin`. So, in Nix terminology, the `(host, target)` of the `gcc` dependency **for this build** is `(x86_64-linux, aarch-darwin)`… (you can see that we do not keep the `build` since who cares on which platform `gcc` was built?) You see of course that this tuple is relative to the current derivation (answering question 4), in the sense that if you compile another program, `gcc` might be assigned another tuple, for instance if `gcc` is called at run-time, say if you want to build a code editor that might run `gcc` at runtime.

Note that if your dependency is not a compiler, then the `target` part of the `(host, target)` tuple is irrelevant. So for instance, if `g++` needs some libraries at runtime, like `glibc` or `perl`, then the `(host, target)` can be simplified into just one `host` like `(host, *)`, here `(aarch64-darwin, *)`. But it also does not hurt to give `target` a value anyway, so why not giving it the value `(aarch64-darwin, aarch64-linux)` (which is the what `buildInputs` will configure, if you want `(aarch64-darwin, aarch64-darwin)`, then use `depsHostHost` as explained [here](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-stdenv-dependencies-reference)).

Then, to answer your last question, you can easily see that you need a way to specify the `(host, target)` somehow. The choice that was made is that:

- `-1` is just a shortcut for `build of current derivation` (so here, `-1` = `x86_64-linux`)
- `0` is just a shortcut for `host of current derivation` (so here, `0` = `aarch64-darwin`)
- `1` is just a shortcut for `target of current derivation` (so here, `1` = `aarch64-linux`)
  Therefore, we can easily convert the above tuple for `glibc` is `(aarch64-darwin, aarch64-linux)`, i.e. `(0,1)`, while the tuple for `gcc` is `(x86_64-linux, aarch64-darwin) = (-1,0)`.

The reason of this choice is that if you want to know the `host` (i.e. where it should run) of the dependency of a dependency of a dependency…, you just sum the `host` value of the dependency to the `host` value of the dependency of the dependency, to the `host` value of the dependency of the dependency of the dependency etc… Note that this process will also stop if the number goes beyond `-1` or `1` in order to:

> prune transitive dependencies whose combined offsets go out-of-bounds, which can be viewed as a filter over that transitive closure removing dependencies that are blatantly absurd.

Finally, you certainly wonder how to specify that `g++` has a dependency whose tuple is `(0,1)`, i.e. that will be run on the host and compile to the target architecture? The whole conversion table is given [here](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-stdenv-dependencies-reference):

[image]

where the offset is the corresponding tupple. So here, you see that the tuple `(-1,0)` is provided by `nativeBuildInputs = [ gcc ];` while the tuple `(0,1)` is provided by `buildInputs = [ glibc perl ];`.