# How should this table of platforms of dependencies be read?

Tags: dependencies, nix, nixos, package-management

https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-stdenv-dependencies-reference says

> A dependency is said to be propagated when some of its
> other-transitive (non-immediate) downstream dependencies also need it
> as an immediate dependency. [3]
>
> It is important to note that dependencies are not necessarily
> propagated as the same sort of dependency that they were before, but
> rather as the corresponding sort so that the platform rules still line
> up. To determine the exact rules for dependency propagation, we start
> by assigning to each dependency a couple of ternary numbers (-1 for
> build, 0 for host, and 1 for target) representing its dependency type,
> which captures how its host and target platforms are each “offset”
> from the depending derivation’s host and target platforms. The
> following table summarize the different combinations that can be
> obtained:
>
> ```
> host → target         attribute name          offset
> build --> build       depsBuildBuild          -1, -1
> build --> host        nativeBuildInputs       -1, 0
> build --> target      depsBuildTarget         -1, 1
> host --> host         depsHostHost            0, 0
> host --> target       buildInputs             0, 1
> target --> target     depsTargetTarget        1, 1
> ```

I was wondering how to read the table?

What do the arrows in "host → target" and "build --> build" mean?

How are the offsets calculated?

Comment: This stuff only matters if you a cross-compiling.  I recommend just putting your dependencies into the `buildInputs` attribute and then come back to this if you actually are cross-compiling and get some error about a propagated dependency being compiled for the wrong platform.

Answer (score 1):

So this is quite close to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77495377/what-are-the-host-and-target-platforms-of-a-dependency), and it turns out that my new answer there answer this question as well. Long story short, if you do not build compilers, then you just want to use `nativeBuildInputs` for dependencies needed at compilation time (`cmake`, `pkg-build` etc), and `buildInputs` for everything else.

For more advanced use-cases, the table you see has two redundant columns: `offset` is just a numeric translation of the first column, where:

- `-1`=`build` (architecture of the machine that builds the program),
- `0`=`host` (architecture of the machine that will run the program),
- `1`=`target` (architecture of the machine that will run the programs compiled by your programs if you build a compiler).

So `host -> target` is the same thing as setting the tuple `(0,1)`, and it informally means that the dependency will be run on the `host`, and (if it is a compiler) that it should compile stuff for the architecture `target`.

The column in the middle is the command to call to attribute the corresponding tuple to a dependency: for instance:

```
nativeBuildInput = [ gcc ];
```

will associate `build -> host` to gcc, i.e. states the flavor of `gcc` that is needed is the one running on the `build` architecture, compiling for the `host` architecture.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77495377/what-are-the-host-and-target-platforms-of-a-dependency).